# PowerShell Version check prior to script execution

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

I'm just asking the communitty if they have come across a way to have the a script check what version of POSH is running prior to the execution of the script.  Currently, my work around is the following code:

```
    #region Final Checks

    #//Check to make sure that version of PowerShell is at least 3.0 before preceding.

    If($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -le 2) {
        Throw "This script has not been tested with version 2.0 or older of PowerShell.  Please execute this script from a system that has PowerShell 3.0 or newer installed.  Windows 8/Server 2012 and newer has it installed by default.  Windows 7/Server 2008 R2 can be patched to have 3.0 installed."
        }

    #endregion Final Checks
```

I have this right after defining my parameters.  However, for my own crazy sake, I want the script to preform this check automatically prior to getting into the meat and potato of the script.  A good comparison is using Validate[X] for a parameter.  If an operator tries to provide data that doesn't fit my user, an error is thrown prior to the execution of the script.  Any ideas?  I know that there is nothing in [CmdletBinding()] that does it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `#Requires` at the top of your script as a way of telling PowerShell what your script needs to do it's thing.

In your specific case you would put

```
#Requires -Version 3
```

This will tell PowerShell that ***at least*** PowerShell Version 3 is needed, if someone tries to run the script with PowerShell Version 2 they will receive the following message:

> The script 'version3.ps1' cannot be run because it contained a "#requires" statement at line 1 for Windows PowerShell version 3.0. The version required by the script does not match the currently running version of Windows PowerShell version 2
>   .0.
>   At line:1 char:2
>   + & <<<<  C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\version3.ps1
>       + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (version3.ps1:String) [], ScriptRequiresException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptRequiresUnmatchedPSVersion

In addition to Version you can require other things as well, all of which are listed in about_Requires on TechNet: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847765.aspx

```
#Requires -Version 4
#Requires -Module MyCmdlets

Write-Host "If you see this, you are running Version 4 and have the MyCmdlets Module available"
```

Comment: HOLY BATMAN!  I have to say they keep adding awesome things into POSH with every version.  This works and thanks for the awesome answer.  I had absolutely no idea about #Requires as I really don't dabble with manifests too much.  Now I have that to add to my toolbox.  I seriously wish I could up vote about three more times as your answer had examples, references and a great explanation.  Happy Scripting!

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

#Requires was added in PowerShell 5 Will not work in earlier versions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).